# What is a Spanned Word?™

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

So, I've been "inspired" by JLee's great series of Word™/Phrase™ puzzles to make my own. (It's not stealing an idea if I call it "inspiration"!) As usual: each sentence contains two marked words, one of which is a Spanned Word™ and one of which is not, and the actual sentences are just for context.

> 1. The guru said, "at least one of you has (**GREEN / BLUE**) eyes."
> 2. You have limited weighings to find the odd coin among (**NINE / TWELVE**).
> 3. In the Monty Hall problem, one of your options is to (**STICK / SWITCH**).
> 4. I hope you will find this puzzle (**INVENTIVE / DIFFICULT**).
> 5. This puzzle's solution may depend on (**SHAPE / SHAPES**).
> 6. Will similar words make this puzzle (**EASIER / SIMPLER**)?
> 7. Or will you focus too much on the (**DIFFERENCE / DISTINCTION**)?
> 8. Don't work on this for too long or you may become (**CONFUSED / ENTRANCED**.)
> 9. I hope this puzzle isn't too (**HARD / EASY**)!
> 10. I can't think of any other relevant sentences so here are some things that annoy me: (**INTERRUPTIONS / NOISE**) and (**STUBBORNNESS / INFLEXIBILITY**).
> 11. (By the way, the previous sentence's pairs were (**INDEPENDENT / UNRELATED**).)
> 12. Good luck solving this (**CONUNDRUM / CHALLENGE**)!

So, what is this property that makes a word a Spanned Word™?

Hint:

> NOISE and HINT are  Spanned Word™s; FEET is a special case of a Spanned Word™.

Hint 2:

> These could also be called Traversable Words.

Hint 3:

> Font and case both matter. SHAPE is Spanned; SHAPES is not.

Comment: Do things like case and font factor into whether a word is a Spanned Word™?

Comment: @Riddler: Yes, they do.

Comment: Is the first word in the set always the spanned word, or could it be either one?

Comment: @Dsel: It could be either.

Comment: Could we get another hint?

Comment: @alexmc: Done. Starting to think this is too unfair - would anyone like me  to send them the solution to see if it's a decent puzzle?

Comment: @Deusovi - I am not sure but to add a data point I have spent ~4hrs attempting this without success so far.

Comment: @IfTrue: That could just mean it's difficult instead of being unfair. I'm hoping it'll make sense when someone finally gets it, rather than seeming like a copout.

Comment: The obvious idea is that if the word were a bridge, it would be possible to walk across. So maybe walking with alternating feet, which would make the second S in SHAPES different from the first. But I haven't found anything consistent. U seems to occur in only one word of the pair, and we know INTERRUPTIONS is not spanned

Comment: Now that the intended solution has been revealed (see below), I am downvoting this -- not because of the solution itself, but because at least three of the examples don't actually fit the intended solution, which makes it near-impossible for anyone to solve.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: I completely understand. Do you think it should be deleted?

Comment: No, I think the premise of the puzzle itself is okay; it's just a little flawed in the execution.  I wouldn't delete it, as it's still a good idea overall.  Editing out the errors in the original question helps, so that future puzzlers have a chance at finding the solution themselves.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: Alright. Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. GREEN / BLUE

   > GREEN
2. NINE / TWELVE

   > NINE
3. TETRIS / PRISMS

   > TETRIS
4. STICK / SWITCH

   > STICK?
5. INVENTIVE / DIFFICULT

   > INVENTIVE
6. SHAPE / SHAPES

   > SHAPE
7. DISTRACTION / DIVERSION
   n/a
8. EASIER / SIMPLER

   > SIMPLER
9. DIFFERENCE / DISTINCTION

   > DIFFERENCE
10. CONFUSED / ENTRANCED

    > ENTRANCED
11. HARD / EASY

    > HARD
12. INTERRUPTIONS / NOISE

    > NOISE
13. STUBBORNNESS / INFLEXIBILITY

    > STUBBORNNESS
14. THIEVES / LAWYERS

    > LAWYERS
15. INDEPENDENT / UNRELATED

    > INDEPENDENT
16. CONUNDRUM / CHALLENGE

    > CHALLENGE

So this is the solution:

> SpannedWords are words you can "walk over". Sometimes gaps are allowed, but only if there is a "way" from letter to letter.
>  This is way FEET is a special SpannedWort; there are no (as in zero) gaps between the "top strokes".
>  That's why SHAPES is not a SpannedWord because there is no connection between the E and S at the end.

Comment: That what I thought by reading the puzzle. Exactly the same.. :)   But challenge would be spanned too?!

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right.

Comment: Nicely done! My precise idea was that there was a continuous path between each letter if you removed all of the spaces in between letters - that is, draw the bounding boxes and remove the space in the middle of them.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the space in the middle of them"?  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "continuous path"?  My apologies, but I find this difficult to grasp.

Comment: @Dennisdeems: Draw the smallest possible (upright) rectangle that you can around every letter, then place them adjacent to each other - you're removing the spaces in between letters. A word is spanned if there is a path that goes from the far left side to the far right. I'll add pictures tonight to explain if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Deusovi Your criteria are ambiguous.  According to your criteria, both answers for #3 are valid, and no answer for #9 is valid (the **ES** in DIFFERENCES and the **ST** and **CT** in DISTINCTIONS).  There is also no valid answer for #14 (**ES** in THIEVES and **AW** in LAWYERS).

Comment: @Deusovi I should also note that using your criteria, several of the individual answers in this post are incorrect (#7 and #8 at least, and probably several more).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: That was stupid of me. I thought I had double checked it both the puzzle itself and his answers.

Comment: I claim victory!

Comment: Though I still don't really understand...

Comment: Just to add this was an idea I had 30 minutes into trying to solve this and due to the numerous sets of words that defied it I ruled it out.

Answer (score 0):

1.The guru said, "at least one of you has (GREEN / BLUE) eyes."

> GREEN is a spanned word.

2.You have limited weighings to find the odd coin among (NINE / TWELVE).

> NINE is spanned.

3.One of the most popular Puzzling.SE posts is about (TETRIS / PRISMS).

> TETRIS is spanned.

4.In the Monty Hall problem, one of your options is to (STICK / SWITCH).

> SWITCH is spanned.

5.I hope you will find this puzzle (INVENTIVE / DIFFICULT).

> INVENTIVE is spanned.

6.This puzzle's solution may depend on (SHAPE / SHAPES).

> SHAPE is spanned.

7.Of course, that might just be a (DISTRACTION / DIVERSION).

> DISTRACTION is spanned.

8.Will similar words make this puzzle (EASIER / SIMPLER)?

> EASIER is spanned.

9.Or will you focus too much on the (DIFFERENCES / DISTINCTIONS)?

> Both words are spanned.

10.Don't work on this for too long or you may become (CONFUSED / ENTRANCED.)

> ENTRANCED is spanned.

11.I hope this puzzle isn't too (HARD / EASY)!

> Both words are spanned.

12.I can't think of any other relevant sentences so here are some things that annoy me: (INTERRUPTIONS / NOISE), (STUBBORNNESS / INFLEXIBILITY), and (THIEVES / LAWYERS).

13.(By the way, the previous sentence's pairs were all (INDEPENDENT / UNRELATED).)

14.Good luck solving this (CONUNDRUM / CHALLENGE)!

> CHALLENGE is spanned.

If my guesses are correct, Spanned words

> have lines separating the letter in half in at least half of the word. (If it has to be over half, that might eliminate some of the duplicates I discovered.)
> Examples would be AEHINTZ who all divide themselves (with spanners, I guess if you want to call them that).

Note that the font changes when you start editing.

> M and W don't look the same when you're typing your answers.

Comment: Thanks, I was mid edit when I got the notice that you'd fixed it.

Comment: Nope. There is exactly one Spanned Word™ in each pair, as I said in the original post. Good guess, though!